# Ended program (Flask) keeps sending output to STDOUT?

Tags: python, linux, bash, flask, sigint

I'm going totally crazy here. I'm developing a website using the Python [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org) and since this afternoon my Linux box is behaving like a mad man. Let me explain.

I've got my Flask website on an Ubuntu 14.04 server. I normally run it using `./run.py` file using a virtualenv. Today I installed some packages and finally decided I wanted a clean env again. So I deleted my `venv` folder and created it again, like a did a million times before:

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ . venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ pip install -r requirements.txt
# EVERYTHING INSTALLS WITHOUT ERRORS
(venv) $ ./run.py
/home/kramer65/mysite/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:100: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
 * Restarting with inotify reloader
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 219-856-383
/home/kramer65/mysite/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:100: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

This is all pretty much as expected. I then proceed to my browser and load my website (also like I did a million times before). The browser loads a very long time, but nothing gets loaded. In the browser console I don't even see any connection opening at all.

I then check the terminal and see nothing happening either. So I stop the dev server using a CTRL+C and get the following output (as expected):

```
^CException in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/kramer65/mysite/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/watchdog/observers/inotify_buffer.py", line 59, in run
    inotify_events = self._inotify.read_events()
  File "/home/kramer65/mysite/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/watchdog/observers/inotify_c.py", line 296, in read_events
    event_buffer = os.read(self._inotify_fd, event_buffer_size)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

So I check out any network connections which are open:

```
$ netstat -tulpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6127/python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:24675           0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp6       0      0 :::22996                :::*                                -
```

So I decide to kill the python process on port 5000 using `kill 6127`. What then happens just stunns me. The command gets "accepted" (I get no error), but then I see the browser suddenly loads the website and the terminal starts outputting logs:

```
(venv) $ kill 6127
(venv) $ 83.161.103.21 - - [2016-04-13 13:59:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7334 0.045281
83.161.103.21 - - [2016-04-13 13:59:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7334 0.062855
83.161.103.21 - - [2016-04-13 13:59:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7334 0.080915
83.161.103.21 - - [2016-04-13 13:59:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7334 0.099523
83.161.103.21 - - [2016-04-13 13:59:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7334 0.118382
83.161.103.21 - - [2016-04-13 13:59:45] "GET /bower/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css?version=3.3.5 HTTP/1.1" 304 745 0.006047
83.161.103.21 - - [2016-04-13 13:59:45] "GET /bower/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css?version=1448904482.0 HTTP/1.1" 304 745 0.003684
etc. etc.
```

And from this I don't understand anything. I get the output even though I thought I stopped the dev-server using CTRL+C and ran two commands in between (`netstat -tulpn` and `kill 6127`).

I can then hit enter a couple times, which gets me my start line again, and then run arbitrary commands:

```
(venv) $
(venv) $
(venv) $ pwd
/home/kramer65/mysite
(venv) $
```

and when I reload the website in the browser I simply get the output again in the same terminal window. My commands, any output of my commands, and the Flask dev-server logs just all get outputted in the same terminal window.

I tried rebooting the server, completely removing all website code and removing and installing the virtualenv again, and I even created a new user and installed everything in there, but I get this same result over and over again.

The thing is that I don't know WHY I get this result. Is it because of Flask, because of the virtualenv, because of some weird bug with the network, because of bash or even something else?!

And most importantly, I have no idea how I can solve this. Does anybody have any idea? All tips are welcome, because I'm pulling out my hair here..

[EDIT]

I ran `$ ps -eaf | grep python`, with the following results:

```
$ ps -eaf | grep python
immotest  1489  1444  0 14:33 pts/1    00:00:00 venv/bin/python ./run.py
immotest  1497  1489  1 14:33 pts/1    00:00:00 /home/kramer65/mysite/venv/bin/python ./run.py
immohie+  1510  1374  0 14:34 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto python
```

Comment: If you run a ps -eaf | grep python does it show anything else apart from the netstat output?

Comment: @lapinkoira - Nothing really interesting. I added the result to the end of the question. Any idea?

Comment: I would need to check the run.py code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already suspected it had something to do with the Flask dev server which spawns a new process to be able to restart itself upon code changes. I had added [watchdog](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/) to requirements.txt because I use it to sync code from my laptop to my Linux dev server.

The Flask dev server works with Watchdog, but for some reason on this machine it wasn't. After removing watchdog from the server everything works fine again. I wasn't able to isolate the problem with a minimal Flask application.